# Why did Joshua go to Murtaugh's house instead of fleeing?

Tags: analysis, lethal-weapon

During Lethal Weapon, after Riggs and Murtaugh escape their captives after being tortured, Riggs chases down Joshua, the mercenary, but he gets away.  Joshua then proceeds to go to Murtaugh's house, presumably to use his family for some reason.

Why did Joshua choose to go to Murtaugh's house, instead of fleeing the city after everything went south?  What did he hope to achieve there?

Comment: Maybe because he's crazy and wants some kind of vengeance? Just a guess, though.

Answer (score 2):

He probably wanted vengence before fleeing the city.  He pulled up and noticed that there were only two officers there.  It looked like a pretty easy walk in - kill - walk out, probably only taking a couple of minutes.

He had no way of knowing that Riggs and co had beaten him there and had laid an ambush.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the movie recently again on tv. First obvious choice is his vengeance. If you rollback to the start of the movie in that initial scene in bar where he puts his hand out on the lighter for his boss to show his loyalty, so I think it could be part vengeance and part loyalty to his boss to kill off the people who hindered his boss and even if it means as to walking onto an ambush (which he never saw coming).